# What does ? do in this Ruby expression?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

On the [Chef Style Guide](https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html) page appears this Ruby expression:

```
antarctica_hint = hint?('antarctica')
```

What exactly does the ? after hint and before ('antarctica') mean? Is it just part of the method name? (i.e. the method is called 'hint?' not 'hint')

Answer (score 6):

It is part of method name, and people typically (not always) use it for methods that return boolean value.

An example from Ruby is [`Class#respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F)